# Help understand a proof of convergence in probability implying convergence in $r$th mean

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm reading a textbook proof of the following claim:
[image]

The proof is as following:
[image]

I'm feeling confused about the contradiction here. Does having a subsubsequence $X_{n^{''}} \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ imply that the $X_{n^{'}}\xrightarrow{r} X$? Is there such a theorem?

The following image is the theorems that the proof used:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it definitely does not; though the proof you copied from the book does not assert that.

The subsequence chosen was a special one: it was chosen as a subsequence that is supposed to stay away from $X$ in $r$th mean. So, the contradiction arises when you analyze some subsubsequence of this special subsequence, and showed that it is indeed close to $X$ in $r$th mean.